# Delete text form textfile with php

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, text-files, file-get-contents

I try to delete some texte in a text file.

The texte file is like that :

```
#MESSAGE
:0
* ^(To|cc).*fd.*
|/usr/bin/vacation fd
#monfiltreperso
:0
* ^From.*martial@gironde.com
Maildir/.repertorymoi
#FIN
#monfiltreperso2
:0
* ^Subject:.*monsujet2
Maildir/.repertorymoi2
#FIN
#monfiltreperso3
:0
* ^From.*martial2@gironde.com
Maildir/.repertorymoi2
#FIN
```

I try to delete the line between **#monfiltre...** and **#monfiltre...**

I have this :

```
$pattern = '~'.'#filtre'.$nom.'\s*\n^#monfiltre~';
$filecontent = preg_replace($pattern, '', $filecontent);
```

So i can delete this line :

> ```
> #monfiltreperso
> :0
> * ^From.*martial@gironde.com
> Maildir/.repertorymoi
> ```

But there is **#FIN**  that is not deleted.

And i have :

> ```
>  #MESSAGE
> :0
> * ^(To|cc).*fd.*
> |/usr/bin/vacation fd
> #FIN  (need to be deleted)
> :0
> * ^Subject:.*monsujet2
> Maildir/.repertorymoi2
> #FIN
> ```

I need to change this rules :

```
$pattern = '~'.'#filtre'.$nom.'\s*\n^#monfiltre~';
```

But I didn't find how.

Comment: Adding [`s` identifier](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove the portion between `#monfiltre*` until `#FIN`, you can use this expression:

```
echo preg_replace('/^#monfiltreperso$.+?^#FIN$[\r\n]*/ms', '', $str);
```

It uses the multiline mode `/m` so that you can match against `^` (start of line) and `$` (end of line). To match across multiple lines, you need the dot-match-all mode `/s`; otherwise it will match until the end of each line.

An optional set of newline characters is matched as well to prevent empty lines from appearing in the end result.

[**Expression visualization**](http://regex101.com/r/kQ3gT5)

You can make it dynamic if you want:

```
$filter = preg_quote('perso3', '/');
echo preg_replace('/^#monfiltre' . $filter . '$.+?^#FIN$[\r\n]*/ms', '', $str);
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try this:

```
$pattern = '~#monfiltreperso\s*\n\K.+?(?=#monfiltreperso2)~s';
echo preg_replace($pattern, '', $texte);
```

or if you are sure to not have any # before `#monfiltreperso2`, you can use this:

```
$pattern = '~#monfiltreperso\s*\n\K[^#]++~';
```

Comment: yep it's work, but **#monfiltreperso** is not remove. whatever i use an another preg_replace to removes **#monfiltreperso**. Thx @casimir-et-hippolyte !

Comment: @MartialE: OK! to do this, just remove the `\K`

Comment: Yep, i just fine the solution when you post ^^ Thx again, You make my day! :)

Comment: I edit my subject, can you see it, my problem is little bit more complicated. @casimir-et-hippolyte